# Is there google or yahoo api to send email?

Tags: php, google-api, email, yahoo-api

I have a PHP web application which needs to send emails 'for' a user through their gmail/yahoo account. We are already storing the user's access tokens for both yahoo and gmail.

Basically all mail sent from the application should go from the user's yahoo/gmail account and should appear in their "sent mail" folder.

So are there any yahoo or gmail api that will allow me to send end emails using the users access tokens?

I did find this for yahoo: http://developer.yahoo.com/mail/docs/user_guide/SendMessage.html. Is this the right one to use?? Is there a similar api for gmail?

Comment: i think gmail supports oauth https://developers.google.com/google-apps/gmail/oauth_libraries

Comment: I did see this link. So I will have to sent mail through SMTP and then create a mail manually in the sent mail folder using imap?
Is this the correct approach?

Comment: You can just connect to the gmail smtp server and use OAuth for the auth type and specify the user's oauth token.  See the [example here](https://developers.google.com/google-apps/gmail/oauth_protocol#smtp_protocol_exchange)

Comment: I think the good news is Gmail will create the sent mail copy automatically. Adding another one though IMAP is unnecessary and even undesired.

Answer (score 0):

Please see the following docs,i think it may be useful to u

https://developers.google.com/google-apps/gmail/oauth_overview

Comment: This seems like a small bit better suited for a comment. You can expand this to be appropriate for an answer by providing your own explanation (you already have a nice primary source to cite) and code examples

Answer (score 0):

I believe this may be of interest, just gone live: https://developers.google.com/gmail/api/